# Model returning null from drop down

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

I have created a dropdown list with a value selected but when I go to save it it returns a null value to the model.

My code for creating the List

```
var startYearList = from r in Model.Facility.Reports.OrderByDescending(x => x.Year)
            select new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = r.Year == null ? "0000" : r.Year.ToString(),
                Value = r.Year == null ? "1/1/0001" : "1/1/" + r.Year.ToString(),
                Selected = (r.Year == Convert.ToInt32((Model.StartDate != null ? Model.StartDate.Value.ToString("yyyy") : "0001")))
            };
```

My code for populating the drop down list.

```
    <div>
        <b>Mailing Address:</b><br />
        <label>Address 1</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address1)<br />
        <label>Address 2</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address2)<br />
        <span class="dynLocation">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Zipcode.Id)</span><br />
        <br />
        From @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StartDate.Value, startYearList)            
        to @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EndDate.Value, endYearList, "Current")            
    </div>
```

The end date can be null

Comment: Can you share the offending "save" snippet also, including signature?

Comment: You need to bind to your property `m => m.StartDate` (not `m => m.StartDate.Value`). And when you create the `SelectList`, there is no point setting the `Selected` property - its ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You binding you dropdown lists to the `Value` property of `Nullable<DateTime>` which is a readonly property ([refer documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6.aspx)) and cant be set when you post back. Instead you need to bind to the property

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StartDate, startYearList)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EndDate, endYearList, "Current")
```

Side notes

1. You should be generating the `SelectList` in the controller, not the
   view, and assigning it to (preferably) a view model property or a
   `ViewBag` property
2. Do not try to set the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem`. You
   are binding to a model property and its the value of the property
   that determines whats selected (the `Selected` value of
   `SelectListItem` is just ignored)
3. A html `<label>` element is an accessibility element designed to
   allow you to set focus to the associated control Your usage of
   `label>Address 1</label>` does not associate the label with the
   control (you may as well just use `<span>Address 1</span>`). Instead
   use `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address1, "Address 1")` or add the
   `[Display(Name = "Address 1")]` attribute to the property and use
   `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address1)`

Comment: The refer documentation doesn't work.  and when I tried to change the code to be like what you recommended it didn't work it does not have a selected value

Comment: After looking up I was able to find the issue.

Comment: Value = r.Year == null ? "01/01/0001" : "1/1/" + r.Year.ToString() + " 12:00:00 AM",

Comment: I've updated the link. No idea what you mean by your last comment, but it appears you still don't understand. You CANNOT bind to the `Value` property of `Nullable<DateTime>` because its a readonly property

Comment: The issue was that in the drop down menu I had to create it with " 12:00:00 AM" because it would not bind correctly because it was not exact.

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. It still will not bind correctly because you are trying to bind to the read-only `Value` property of `Nullable<DateTime>` But why would you do this anyway. Since you want the 1st day of the selected year, you should have a view model property `int Year` and then in the controller your generate the date based on the selected year.

Comment: I had it originally set to the way you had mentioned but it would then not hold the default value. The year that is coming from the database when it is passed through the dbms ends up with a 12:00:00 am on it which then does not match exactly causing the drop down to not have a default.  So in order to fix it when I was creating the drop down I had to add the time to it.

Comment: That's not necessary at all, so there must have been some other issue with your code. Not sure what you mean by _not hold the default value_ though. Is the field in the database a `date` or just an `int` (storing only the year component)?

Comment: It was stored as a date.  As soon as I added the time to the date I was creating (I am storing the whole date in the database not just the year).  The defaults worked.

Answer (score -1):

In cases where a model value is nullable I have found that using Html.DropDownList works better.

You will likely find that the name of the generated select list is "StartDate_Value"  and as such does not correspond to the variable name in the model.

```
 @Html.DropDownList("StartDate", startYearList)
```

Comment: this is the issue Value = r.Year == null ? "01/01/0001" : "1/1/" + r.Year.ToString() + " 12:00:00 AM",